# Shared hosting: using a custom Perl version for CGI

Tags: apache-2.2, perl, shared-hosting

I'm trying to revamp some nasty old sites on a cheap shared host using one of these new-fangled Perl web frameworks (Dancer).  I had module dependency problems with the existing Perl install (5.6.1) so I built a new (5.12) version locally.

The new Perl version seems to work fine when testing my app or using the development server, and I was hoping I could just change the shebang the CGI script to point to my new Perl and Apache would serve it ok.  Unfortunately in the Apache error log I just get:

```
failed to open log file
fopen: Permission denied
[Thu Dec  9 14:45:21 2010] [error] [client 138.***.***.***] Premature end of script headers: /home/www/hosts/blahblah/cgi-bin/bb/public/dispatch.cgi
```

This seems to indicate Apache can't find or execute my new Perl version, but I can't see why not.

I've checked the permissions on my local Perl and they're all 755, which I though user **www** would be able to access and execute ok.  Now I've run out of ideas?  Is there anything else I can try?

I can SSH in to the hosting server but don't have root perms or access to the Apache config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I should "answer" this myself but I eventually figured it out the problem.  I'd installed my own version of Perl in a ~/perl5 directory, but Apache could apparently only see inside ~/www (a symlink pointing to my domain name.)  Rebuilding Perl and all the modules inside ~/www/perl5 fixed things.

Lessons learned:

- if I'd configured Perl with "relative @INC paths" option enabled I could have just moved the whole lot and saved myself a bunch of time - it's **not** the default though.
- cpanm (App::cpanminus on CPAN) is a real time-saver for installing Perl modules and their dependencies if you're in a restricted environment and can't get regular CPAN to work.

Unlikely this'll help someone in a similar situation but you never know.

(Incidentally, now I've solved the build/run problems, running a modern framework like Dancer doesn't seem to be working out with regular old CGI.  There might be some config issues remaining but it seems **incredibly** slow to serve my tiny app.  But those are problems for a different SF question.)

Comment: I'm about 7 years late, but for what it's worth... Dancer runs on PSGI/Plack. It loads Moo (and other things) that have quite a bit of startup. The idea is that it runs in a persistent process. It can interface via Plack to be run as CGI, but that's a real resource-hog. If you want to stick with your Apache, use an FCGI handler and plackup or server_starter.

Comment: However, I came here for the CGI specifically. Thanks for the advice.